# Facebook Facepile Integration

Tags: html, facebook

I want to integrate Facebook Facepile plugin to one website. However, according to this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile

The plugin is deprecated, and will stop working. So I want to find any alternative to do so, but I was not able to find any further information on the Internet. Could some one help me to find any alternatives to realize that ?

Best,
Mario P.

Comment: For Facebook pages, you should use the new Page Plugin – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: Thank you for your help. I already implemented Page Plugin yesterday :)